# Tomcat enable listing only in a folder

Tags: tomcat, directory-listing

How can I enable the direcotry listing *only* in a particular folder inside Apache Tomcat 7?
I alredy tried to add this

```
 <init-param>
            <param-name>listings</param-name>
            <param-value>false</param-value>
</init-param>
```

in the global **web.xml** but it enables the listing of *all* folder

Comment: Follow [this](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/default-servlet.html#dir) link . If you want to enable this for only an individual folder, you've got to write some Servlet I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way you can do this with configuration is to enable listing for all folders within a web application and then ensure a welcome file is present for all folders you don't want listings for.

The other (non-configuration) approach would be to extend Tomcat's default Servlet, add whatever listing logic you require and then configure your custom version as the default servlet for your application.